# How to remove or disable McAfee File and Removable Media Protection

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, disk-encryption

How to remove or temporary disable **McAfee File and Removable Media Protection**? It wants to encrypt USB devices anytime they are plugged in or otherwise it sets them to read only. Any idea how to get rid of that annoying feature?

There is a note on that here:
https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB81439
however I do not know how to find **cd Product_Installation_Path** which is mentioned there.

Maybe there is some lighter way to unchecked that option somewhere?

Comment: Please confirm the OS version and detail which this software is installed, and specify whether or not this is a company laptop or joined to a domain, Also, why did you install this if you didn't need it or why did someone else, and perhaps there's just a misconfiguration with the software that can be changed to adjust the behavior as you describe such as an admin portal or interface, etc.

Comment: I wanted to send you this too https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB81433 just so you can read over the installation from command line and paths, etc. for what that says just in case you find it helpful any to troubleshoot. If you have support on this product, it may be a good time to reach out to the vendor and they'll know for sure how their product works.

Comment: @Walmart Windows 7 Professional. Let's leave the reasons aside please. Suppose the aim is to disable just this feature not the entire Mcafee and suppose in achieving it you do not have to bother with configuration of the software.

Comment: Sure would you at least mind disclosing if this is a domain joined machine or has policies pushed to it from an Enterprise level entity e.g. McAfee ePO? If there are policies enforcing this then looking at that level may have the answer. If you can find the **cd Product_Installation_Path** by searching the "C" (e.g. `~/Program Files`, etc.) drive for applicable files, you may be able to use that method from that post I suppose. I'm not familiar with this particular production to know anything definitive.

Comment: Honestly, I'd remove McAfee. It's utter garbage compared to any other protection software and has caused more harm than good on any computer I've had the privilege of repairing. I know my comment doesn't answer your question, but I've never had a good experience with the program. Ever. Anyone I've ever worked with has recommended Norton, Kaspersky, or Malwarebytes Premium if you need a protection software. Sounds odd that it would want to encrypt the drive... Maybe there's an option somewhere, or it's wrongly installed. That should definitely not be a default setting on ANY software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if it works but it seems so:

1. Windows key + R (Run) and type: msconfig.exe
2. Move to tab [Start up]
3. Uncheck anything that starts with McAfee. Probably unchecking just [McAfee, Inc.(R) Endpoint Encryption for Files and Folders] suffices.
4. Do not know if it is necessary but go to tab [Services] and uncheck anything that starts with McAfee.
5. Restart. You are done.

You can easily check it back the same way. Beware! I do not know if McAfee policy allows to turn it off that way. Could be another question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Przemyslaw Remin is mostly correct, however, upon reboot, "McAfee File and Removable Media Protection" starts again even if it is disabled from the Startup unless you have disabled the Encryption Core Services.

1. Open Task Manager
2. Move to [Start up] tab
3. Disable McAfee File and Removable Media Protection Main User Mode Application
4. Move to [Services] tab
5. Stop McAfee Endpoint Encryption Core Services then Open Services and disable this service
6. You can also go to "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Encryption for Files and Folders" (adjust as appropriate for your setup) and rename MfeFfCore.exe

Please note that I am *not* using McAfee Drive Encryption for my hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [McAfee Knowledge Center](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB81450#Func_EERM)

> Can users stop the FRP Removable Media services to disable the encryption policy?
>   **No.** You can only disable the encryption policy via the FRP Removable Media policy at the ePO server.

So, the only option will be uninstall it, as described on [KB81439](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB81439)

The line "cd Product_Installation_Path" means: you have to go to installed folder, like:

```
C:\> cd "Program files\McAfee"
```

Comment: sorry, but where is the difference ?